# Is it possible to save data with multiple keys in Android Firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am studying Android and Firebase by myself.

I'm have a problem with storing user information and creating login and user registration functions by linking Android and Firebase.

When saving user information in Firebase, is only one key possible? I want to save more keys.

I tried changing main key, but it's failed.

Sorry. I can't speak English. I'm using a translator now.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11syr.png)

I saved user information like in the picture, but there was a problem during the production of the ID search function.

```
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); //파이어베이스 데이터베이스 연동
DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference();
DatabaseReference conditionRef = databaseReference.child("User");

conditionRef.child(userID).child("userID").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    String userid = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                    if(snapshot.exists()){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "아이디: " + userid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "등록되지 않은 회원입니다.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
```

The code is as above.
However, because "conditionRef.child(userID)" does not have a userID value, the information cannot be retrieved from Firebase.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to save more keys"? Can you please provide us with an example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.